# JSON Object to Datatables.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a problem about populating datatables.js using json object, Can I use the ajax response value as the data for the datatable?

```
 $.ajax({
  url:"php_action/searchloc.php",
  type:"POST",
  data:{
      origin: $('#from').val(),
      destination: $('#to').val()
      } ,
    dataType:"json",
  success:function(data){

    $('#schedule').dataTable( {
      "ajax": data,
      columns: []
  } );
  },
  error:function(){
    alert("error");

  }
});
```

Comment: The `ajax` property of a DataTable configuration object should the URL that you want to retrieve data from, not the data itself.

Comment: but i need the origin and destination value for my where clause in php

Comment: the `ajax` property can also be an object that contains the `url`, `type` (POST/GET), and `data`. Take a [look at the documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html) for DataTables as it explains all of this. It also mentions that the `ajax` property maps directly to the [jQuery `ajax()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataTables has it's own AJAX functionality that uses jQuery's AJAX method, so you don't need to wrap your dataTable logic inside of a jQuery AJAX call.

```
$('#schedule').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    url:"php_action/searchloc.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{
      origin: $('#from').val(),
      destination: $('#to').val()
    },
    dataType:"json",
    columns: []
  }
} );
```

Comment: Gotcha.. but there are already data in the datatable, how to override the previous data ?

Comment: Take some time to read the documentation: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload() As a developer, you should always read the documentation, since it often times has all of the answers you seek.

Answer (score 0):

use the `data` option :

```
$.ajax({
  url:"php_action/searchloc.php",
  type:"POST",
  data:{
      origin: $('#from').val(),
      destination: $('#to').val()
      } ,
    dataType:"json",
  success:function(result){

    $('#schedule').dataTable( {
      data: result,
      columns: []
  } );
  },
  error:function(){
    alert("error");

  }
});
```

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html